I2C hanging on STM32F103
I am using FreeRTOS to communicate with 10 slaves using I2C in DMA normal mode on a customized PCB board. The code works for a while but I2C hangs sometimes, interrupting the communication.
Initially my code was as follows:
static void vMaster_Slave_i2c_task(void* parameters)
{
   vTaskDelay(100); 

   for(;;)
   {
      for(uint8_t addr_pos=0;addr_pos<NUM_OF_SLAVES;addr_pos++)
      {
         HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(addr_pos<<1), (uint8_t*)&(_slave_params[addr_pos].slave_param), 1,I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME) ;
                                                                                                
         vTaskDelay(10);
                        
         HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(addr_pos<<1), rec_data, 4,I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME);
                                                                              
         vTaskDelay(10);
      }                 
   }
}

When it started hanging somewhere inside the HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA api, I changed the code to the following , as described on the ST example projects:
static void vMaster_Slave_i2c_task(void* parameters)
{
   vTaskDelay(100); 

   for(;;)
   {
      for(uint8_t addr_pos=0;addr_pos<NUM_OF_SLAVES;addr_pos++)
      {
         while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY){}

         while(HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(addr_pos<<1), (uint8_t*)&(_slave_params[addr_pos].slave_param), 1,I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME) != HAL_OK) {}
                                                                                                
         vTaskDelay(10);
    
         while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY){}
                
         while(HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(addr_pos<<1), rec_data, 4,I2C_FIRST_AND_LAST_FRAME) != HAL_OK) {}
                                                                              
         vTaskDelay(10);

      }             
   }
}

It behaves the same way but now it gets stuck at the first while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY){} until I turn off and on the power. I checked with an oscilloscope and there is no SCL pulses when it hangs. I'm using 51K pullup resistors.
When I set a breakpoint an step inside I see the I2C state HAL_TRANSMIT_BUSY . I've no idea why is that. I already made sure that no other peripheral is using DMA1 channels 6 and 7.
And ... I'm using HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA and HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA just because HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA and HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_DMA are not working at all for some reason.
On the project I also have UART1 set up , which uses DMA1 channels 4,5. I can only use UART1 with DMA in reception mode. For transmiting DMA is not working(the api call is just ignored by the compiler ! ) so I'm using blocking mode.
Any tips from you would be helpful.
